# kubernetes cron job which should run every 10mins and should delete the pods which are in "Terminating" state in all the namespaces in the cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, jobs, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, kubernetes-cronjob

kubernetes cron job which should run every 10mins and should  delete the pods 
which are in "Terminating" state in all the namespaces in the cluster? please 
help me out....am struggling with the bash one liner shell script

```
  apiVersion: batch/v1
  kind: Job
  metadata:
  name: process-item-$ITEM
  labels:
  jobgroup: jobexample
  spec:
  template:
  metadata:
  name: jobexample
  labels:
    jobgroup: jobexample
spec:
  containers:
  - name: c
    image: busybox
    command: ["sh", "-c", "echo Processing item $ITEM && sleep 5"]
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: Why you want this?

Comment: in my cluster for some reason pods are going to terminating state and not really terminating it is juts staying in there so i dont want to go to manually each pod and delete the pods which are in terminating state so i am looking for a cron which does that  @cgcgbcbc

Comment: Do you set `pod.Spec.TerminationGracePeriodSeconds` on your pod template so that the terminating pods get killed after a period

Comment: @cgcgbcbc if you dont mind can you post a sample yaml which has this feature?

Comment: @cgcgbcbc i should add this in deployment?

Answer (score 1):

List all terminating pods in all namespace with the format {namespace}.{name}

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Terminating --output=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.namespace}{"."}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}' --all-namespaces=true
```

Given a pod's name and its namespace, it can be force deleted by

```
kubectl delete pods <pod> --grace-period=0 --force --ns=<namespace>
```

In one line

```
for i in `kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Terminating --output=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.namespace}{"."}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}' --all-namespaces=true`; do kubectl delete pods ${i##*.} --grace-period=0 --force --ns=${i%%.*}; done
```